# Fields not present in Request are set to null in entity

Tags: symfony

I make rest api controller. I have a form SliderApiType, in which I pass the fields that I want to edit. If I pass only one field, for example 'label', then only this field will be changed, and all other fields in this form will be null.

Му form:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Заголовок', 'required' => false])
            ->add('description', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Описание', 'required' => false])
            ->add('serialNumber', IntegerType::class, ['label' => 'Номер', 'required' => false])
            ->add('picture', IntegerType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'picture is not a valid',
            ])
            ->add('send', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Отправить'])
        ;

        $builder->get('picture')
            ->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
    }
```

My controller in wherein I make edit action:

```
    public function edit(Slider $slideId, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SliderApiType::class, $slideId);
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $form->submit($data);
        if (!($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())) {
            return $this->handleView($this->view($form->getErrors(true)));
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($slideId);
        $em->flush();

        $context = new Context();
        $context->addGroup('slider_create');
        $view = $this->view($slideId);
        $view->setContext($context);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```

If pass this fields in json:

```
{
  "label": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "picture": 1
}
```

All working good!

But if I pass this json:

```
{
  "label": "string"
}
```

Field "label" set how "string", but fields "description" and "picture" sets null.

How to make it so that if I passed the field, only it was edited, and the other two fields were not null?

Comment: What keeps you from writing code for that? I see no connection between the given code and the JSON input

Comment: I corrected my question a little

Comment: Are you sure that you want to write such a complicated mechanism? Why not transfer all fields?

Comment: Yes, I what it, but I don`n know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't written any rest apis, but with little googling it looks like you can just use the second parameter of the submit function:

```
$form->submit($data, false);
```

This is assuming that your function here is used only for updating existing entity data  (PATCH/PUT method) - if you want to support multiple methods in the same action then you need to check the request method type:

```
$clearMissing = $request->getMethod() != 'PATCH';
$form->submit($data, $clearMissing);
```

Comment: It will not work, I tryed( If you make rest api, you doesn't have $form->submit.

Comment: sorry to hear that it doesn't work. I don't understand what the parenthesis part of your comment means - I'm pretty sure that you have $form->submit available in rest api action handling (there seemed to be many examples about that available - like [restapi patch example](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-rest/patch-programmer))

Comment: You were right, I was inattentive, found $ form-> submit ($ one, false) and set false as the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put this logic directly in your entity. Like that, you are confident that whenever you update the same information, it will apply the same logic instead of only in the controller. Something like this for each fields:

```
public function setField(string $newValue)
{
    if (!empty($newValue)) {
        $this->field = $newValue;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I suggest my problem.I write one string `$form->submit($data, false);` it solved my problem. if you write like me, you won't actually have to write a lot of code.

Comment: Then if you want to retrieve data from API or from the command line or a flat file? Your solution is for  Form and only valid for Form